# Arduino millis() won't work

Tags: millis

This is my program. The LED should turn off after four seconds.

```c++
int vraag = 7;
int gloeikaars = 5;
unsigned long previousMillis3;
boolean gloeistate = true;

void setup() {
    pinMode(gloeikaars, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    int x = digitalRead(vraag);
    if (x == 0) {
        digitalWrite(gloeikaars, !LOW);
    } else {
        Gloeikaars();    
    }
}

// *********************************************************************
// Gloeikaars aansturing
// *********************************************************************
void Gloeikaars() {
    unsigned long huidig = millis();
    digitalWrite(gloeikaars, !HIGH);
    if ((gloeistate == true) && (huidig - previousMillis3 >= 4000)) {
        huidig = previousMillis3;
        digitalWrite(gloeikaars, !LOW);
        gloeistate = false;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me because it won't work?

Comment: At the moment your code doesn't know when you turned the LED on - so how can it know when 4 seconds have passed?

Comment: you are doing pinmode with a function. How do you conclude millis doesn't work?

Comment: @Patrick, I'm also Dutch, but I code in English, not only does it spice up your English, it also works better when working with international people (or StackExchange websites).

Comment: (Dutch, to avoid language barriers) Patrick, het is beter om je programma ook in het Engels te schrijven, zo kunnen internationale collega's ook je programma lezen/begrijpen (of mensen op stack-exchange).
Je vertelt er namelijk ook niet bij dat je een "glowing-candle" probeert te maken, wat uiterst interessant kan zijn voor mensen die je code proberen te begrijpen. Over het algemeen zijn vragen als: "Dit is mijn code, het werk niet" ook geen goede vragen. Beschrijf wat je probeert te doen, welk gedrag je verwacht en wat er gebeurt (dat niet zo zou moeten zijn).

Answer (score 1):

Your `previousMillis` variable is never set.  Two changes:

In setup:

```
...
previousMillis3 = millis();
...
```

In loop:

```
...
previousMillis3 = huidig;
...
```

Comment: Not needed in setup, as both the `millis()` counter and `previousMillis3` are initialized to zero.